# Datastudio: is it possible to export a table in csv automatically?

Tags: google-api, looker-studio

Can you schedule an export of a table in data studio in an excel or csv format?

I know you can schedule an export in a PDF and you can download table as an excel or csv (or export to a Google Sheet), but can I automate that process? Whether it is a daily download of that table to a Google Sheet or a daily email with an excel attachment.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Data Studio API or feature that supports automatic or programmatic export of Data Studio UI elements, including tables. So this is currently not supported in the product.

Comment: is there a roadmap in order to adding this support? This might be really interesting. Instead of going manually and click the "Export CSV", the chance to programmatically do this action would really be appreciated. 

Thanks for the reply Minhaz